# SQL Pivot and formatting Grid

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I used pivot to get data in format

```
Store  department  Employee     Q1         Q2         Q3
----------------------------------------------------------
abc      d1         u1          1          Null       Null
abc      d1         u1          Null       3          Null
abc      d1         u1          Null       Null       2     
abc      d1         u2          1          Null       Null
abc      d1         u2          Null       3          Null
abc      d1         u2          Null       Null       2   
abc      d2         u1          1          Null       Null
abc      d2         u1          Null       3          Null
abc      d2         u1          Null       Null       2
```

I want to group them as

```
Employee             Q1         Q2         q3
------------------------------------------------------------------
u1                   1           3        2
u2                   1           3        2
```

How can i achieve this using sql query or is it possible to directly do it using pivot

Comment: Show us the sql with the pivot that produces the above result ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my query so that i don't have to group and get result as desired

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PIVOTED is the table or query that produce the data you showed

```
select employee, avg(Q1) as Q1, avg(Q2) as Q2, avg(Q3) as Q3
from PIVOTED
group by employee
```

Of course avg could not be the right grouping (min? max?). Tell us more.